# How can I backup my Outlook signatures?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a large number of Outlook 2007 Signatures that I use for pre stored text (saves time answering emails) but now I want to move PC, where are the signatures stored and can I back them up?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find them here:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures
```

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Signatures
```